# Rename branch on merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I currently have an open merge request on GitLab. However, I want to rename the branch which is used for the merge request, without closing the merge request.

Comment: Would it be more helpful to ask this in [their community forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/)?

Comment: As far as I know, that is not possible. Rad this conversation on [GitLab: Rename Branches Propagates to MR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/39910)